# How to determine whether congruence has solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example,

$x^2 ≡ 2 (mod$ $122)$

Is this congruence has solutions? If so, how many solutions it has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has $122=2\times 61$, therefore using [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), $x^2=2\bmod 122$ has a solution if and only if $x^2=0\bmod 2$ and $x^2=2\bmod 61$ have solutions and the number of solutions $\bmod 122$ is the product of the number of solutions $\bmod 2$ and $\bmod 61$.

Remember that $x^2=a\bmod p$ where $a$ is an integer and $p$ is an odd prime number has exactly $\displaystyle 1+\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ solutions, where $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\cdot}{p}\right)$ is the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) $\bmod$ p and is equal to $a^{p(p-1)/2}\bmod p$.

Finally, $x^2=2\bmod 122$ has no solutions.